# News letter preview in front end

Tags: template, controllers, newsletter

I'm very new to magento. I want to show the newsletter template's preview for the customers. I know it is possible from the admin backend. But how can I obtain this link in the template pages?.  I found this code in `core/Mage/AdminHtml/controllers/Newsletter/TemplateController.php`

```
`public function previewAction ()
{
    $this->_setTitle();
    $this->loadLayout();

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    if (empty($data) || !isset($data['id'])) {
        $this->_forward('noRoute');
        return $this;
    }

    // set default value for selected store
    $data['preview_store_id'] = Mage::app()->getAnyStoreView()->getId();

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('preview_form')->setFormData($data);
    $this->renderLayout();
}`.
```

but I don't know how to use it for this. I have the template_id to load the template.

Is there any other method to accomplish this?. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you wan't to show it? And what is actually your plan why you want to achieve this?

Comment: I want to show it on `customer/form/newsletter.phtml`. Actually my client need the preview of all news letters displayed on the newsletter.phtml page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could help, anyway I did not test it:

```
$queue = Mage::getModel('newsletter/queue');
$queue->setTemplateId('YOUR_ID');
$data['preview_store_id'] = Mage::app()->getAnyStoreView()->getId(); //or your store-id
$queue->addTemplateData($data);
$queue->getNewsletterText();

//more:
$this->getNewsletterSubject();
$this->getNewsletterStyles();
```

To get a proper view you will need to include it via iframe or popup-windows I guess.

From my personal experience I can say, that sending Newsletters directly from Magento is not too much fun and it's very inflexible. It would make sense to integrate a newsletter service.

Comment: Till `$data['preview_store_id'] = Mage::app()->getAnyStoreView()->getId();` is working fine but it is stuck in the line `$queue->addTemplateData($data);`. print_r($queue->addTemplateData($data);) shows nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot debug it right now. You should check what happens in the addTemplateData and getTemplate methods of Mage_Newsletter_Model_Queue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this in an indirect way and it worked for me. I directly get all required newsletter data from the database itself.

```
$resource = new Mage_Core_Model_Resource();  
$read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');  
$select = $read->select()->from('newsletter_template');
$temp = $read->fetchAll($select);
```

then simply using a foreach loop, I was able to get all the values.